# Excel file larger after saving and going very slow

Tags: microsoft-excel, memory, macros

I have a 3.5Mb excel workbook with several tabs, only one macro and apparently not pulling data from anywhere in the outside. Nevertheless, when I open it (it takes an obscene amount of time) and I do Ctrl+S it saves itself (again after an unbelievable amount of time) and it weights 4.3Mb now and during the saving procedure an empty text file is created. I have done this repeatedly as I have the 3.5Mb file in my email with the same outcome.

Neither tweaking the main options nor rebooting the PC and excel has yield any success.

Any help would be much appreciated, I am working on a windows 10 and MicrosoftOffice 365 ProPlus with excel version 1808.

Comment: What happens if you disable the macro? If there is more than one worksheet look into the [file structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46846678/how-to-open-and-view-the-xml-structure-of-an-excel-file) to see if a particular sheet is significantly bigger than others. If yes, is it a work sheet that the macro affects? if no, see if a Clear All" of all empty seeming cells helps. If not, you may need to copy only those cells with content to a new sheet and delete the problem sheet.

Comment: Did you check to see if there are formulas? Possibly calculation is occurring?

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. If I delete the macro and save the file the behavior is the same, a heavier file is saved and it won't open afterwards, it says recovering and stalls. Doing as suggested, looking into the file structure I see that there are notable differences in /xl and more particularly in drawings. Is it an issue of how I am saving the file (I have no trouble with the 3.9Mb file)? Furthermore, how can I detect the bottle neck that is causing this trouble from the xml? Thanks for everything

Comment: Look in `\xl\worksheets\` is one of the XMLs there huge compared to the others?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, a cell is edited or formatted at the very end (bottom or right) of excel, which results in all one million empty rows (columns) being saved too.

Try this: hit CTRL+END. It should hop to the last field with data in your sheet. If it goes to the very bottom (or very right), select all one million rows (columns) between your last data and the end, and delete them. Then save, close, and open again. The problem should be gone.